# how controllers in flutter can rebuild widget without calling setstate

Tags: flutter

Some widgets like ListView accept a controller.

but I don't know why for example a controller can update the scroll position by calling `controller.animateTo()` without calling `setState`?

it is a little strange to me what exactly a controller is?
(I know that a controller can be used to customize the behavior of a widget)

and What's going on inside a controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't.

Controllers do not make widgets rebuild. They only provide a way to listen to changes (usually through `ChangeNotifier`/`ValueNotifier`)

It is then another widget that uses this listen mechanism to call setState.

One example would be `AnimatedBuilder`. It's a stateful widget that calls `setState` when `animation` emits some notifications